# How to store data that has a data type larger than the array's?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say I have an array that stores 8 bit integers. How can I read a 32 bit integer from the input and store it within 4 consecutive positions of my array? For instance...

```
uint8_t * myArray = malloc(1024 * sizeof(uint8_t) ); 
scanf("%x", &myArray[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("0x%02x\n"); // %02x prints an integer in HexaDecimal format with 2 0's padding to the left
```

```
INPUT: 
0xAABBCCDD

OUTPUT: 
0xDD
0xCC
0xBB
0xAA
```

Get it? Instead of losing the most significant bits, I want the data to be spread to the following positions. How can I do that? I know it has something to do with pointer arithmetics but I just don't know what.

Comment: Before you even head down this path, first, can you not just change the array to be of type `uint32_t`? Second, can you read the input as a `uint8_t` instead, and just avoid this whole problem?

Comment: @Frontear well the array was allocated by `malloc` so it has no type until written to

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want DD CC BB AA on all systems, or whether you want to use native endianness (i.e. big-endian systems would give AA BB CC DD).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code as you have it now actually works as you want it to in C if you just fix the printf statement:

From this:

```
printf("0x%02x\n");
```

To this:

```
printf("0x%02x\n", myArray[i]);
```

I think your scanf statement is slightly suspect with `%x` as a format specifier (which is unsigned int), but `&myArray[0]` is a byte pointer.  The 4-byte read into a byte address will spill into the next 3 bytes, which are part of your allocated array.

I might code it as follows:

```
uint32_t * myArray = malloc(256 * sizeof(uint32_t)); 
uint8_t* myByteArray = (uint8_t*)myArray;
scanf("%x", &myArray[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("0x%02x\n", myByteArray[i]);
```

And if you want to be a purist about and not rely on pointer hacks.  Assuming you want little endian semantics as you imply:

```
uint32_t* myArray = malloc(256 * sizeof(uint32_t)); 
scanf("%x", &myArray[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
     uint32_t val = ((myArray[i/4] >> (i*8)) & 0x000000ff;
     printf("0x%02x\n", (unsigned int)(val));
}
```

Comment: There's no UB in the original code btw  (the strict aliasing rule refers to the type of the memory being read/written, not any intermediate pointer)

Comment: That assumes the compiler aligned the byte array on an integer boundary. All compilers in practice do this, but I'm not sure what the rule is.  I just learned the hard way many times that programs compiled for Sparc would crash if you deference an integer pointer that wasn't on a 32-bit boundary.  The good old days... answer updated.

Comment: The result of malloc is guaranteed to be aligned for any object

Comment: @M.M - Fixed.  Someone quoted that leftshift and integer overflow thing before, but I never understood what was wrong with `(0xff << 24)` into an unsigned int. Oh I see - it's the reliance on the high order bits getting clipped vs UB.